# Trouble with te link and autofocus on iPhone device with Responsive design

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, responsive-design, tel

I am having a very weird problem. I have converted our site to a first responsive design. On our mobile version I have an a href with a tel:(phone number) styled to appear as an image.

Just below the link is a form we have.  There is javascript to focus the cursor in the first form field.

The trouble I am having is specifically on iPhones. This only happens one the first load of the page first attempt to touch on the tel link to dial the phone number. Try to tap the phone number again and it functions as expected. But the first attempt to tap the phone number and the screen jumps down and focuses in on one of the form fields. But it actually doesn't even focus on the default one that I have it focused on. It will focus on the second or third field, it varies.

Now if I remove the autofocus javascript from the page, then the problem goes away. Trouble is, I definitely want this code on deskptop version of the page.

I am loading the jquery library 1.8.2, jquery tools 1.2.7, and modernizer 2.6.2. Not sure if any of these are causing a conflict.

I would be interested in any of three types of info solution

1. How to turn off the javascript via browser width for responsive design.
2. Iphone debugging tools perhaps.
3. Or a straight up solution of course. =)

Thanks for reading and any help.

Comment: Interesting. I just found out if I use the html5 form input attribute autofocus, I get the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

This handy tool will let you run JS based on mediaqueries: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

1. Remove the Autofocus from the markup.
2. Setup something like:

   if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 480px)').matches) {
   $('element that needs autofocus').attr('autofocus','TRUE');
   }

I admit I don't know the appropriate settings for autofocus on an element off the top of my head, instead of setting the value to "TRUE" it may need a value of "autofocus".